# Problems compiling Ruby

Tags: ruby, compilation

I am trying to install Gitlab CI on a virtual machine, and I am following [this instructions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/5-1-stable/doc/install/installation.md) to do so.

The point #2 is about installing and compiling ruby. When I execute the command `make` I encounter at the end of the process the following error messages:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ext/pty'
compiling pty.c
pty.c: In function ‘chfunc’:
pty.c:143:12: warning: ignoring return value of ‘seteuid’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     seteuid(getuid());
            ^
linking shared-object pty.so
installing default pty libraries
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ext/pty'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ext/racc/cparse'
compiling cparse.c
linking shared-object racc/cparse.so
installing default cparse libraries
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ext/racc/cparse'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ext/readline'
compiling readline.c
readline.c: In function ‘Init_readline’:
readline.c:1886:26: error: ‘Function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     rl_pre_input_hook = (Function *)readline_pre_input_hook;
                          ^
readline.c:1886:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
readline.c:1886:36: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
     rl_pre_input_hook = (Function *)readline_pre_input_hook;
                                    ^
readline.c: At top level:
readline.c:530:1: warning: ‘readline_pre_input_hook’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 readline_pre_input_hook(void)
 ^
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ext/readline'
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p353'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Here is a more long log: http://pastebin.com/m6wzLVd9

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be this bug https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9578. I think you need the most stable version of ruby.

Comment: Do you recommend me installing ruby instead with RVM?

Comment: I think that's the right way to go. Here's a hint https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Installing-Gitlab-with-RVM

Comment: Should I stick with version 2.0.0 as the documentation tries to compile? Or go to 2.1.3?

Comment: I was able to make it work with 1.9.3 before and used this guide https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/3-2-stable/doc/installation.md

Comment: I also seemed to found a solution for the bug here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488790/compile-ruby-2-0-errors-without-rvm-or-rbenv-readline-c188626-error-func